# Trying to manually install SteamOS - can't choose role for partition

Tags: linux, installation, partitioning, steam-os

I'm trying to install SteamOS from hard drive partition where I unzipped installer zip.

I was able to boot into installer with help of my other OS grub, but now I'm stuck at disk partitioning.
In manual partitioning, I can only choose fat16, fat32, swap or none as a partition role.
I can't choose extX and thus I can't specify my root file system.
I'm afraid of using auto partitioning because it will ruin my main hwrd drive and/or overwrite partition with the installer. Please help.

UPD: This might be related to installer not able to find and load modules.
Where should they reside? I guess the normal procedure was disrupted by booting from hdd.
Specifically, extX module is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Valve explicitly said that SteamOS would format completely everything on your PC. I'm assuming that's why you're having problems installing it on a certain partition.

[From Valve's FAQ](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamuniverse/discussions/1/648814395741989999/):

> Q: How do I install SteamOS?
>
> There are two different install methods for SteamOS. '''WARNING: BOTH METHODS WILL ERASE >EVERYTHING ON THE MACHINE'''

Comment: In fact this is easy to override by editing default.preseed script

Comment: Ah, well. I wasn't aware of that. My apologies. I'm sure there is someone else that has come up with a solution on the internet. I would personally check the SteamOS discussions and Forums.

Answer (score 0):

try this first create an empty partition next to your existing os, with any tool your well known.

now install the steamOS with the automatic option and just tell it to use the empty partition.

another posibillity use an external harddrive for the steamOS or maybe also a virtual machine solution will do it.

or have a look out for any multiboot setup howto. and adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my problem arose from trying to boot vmlinuz from install.386

Once I've boot vmlinuz from install.amd (64 bit) it could find all modules, detect hardware and list all file systems. I guess 32-bit installer is broken and Valve should post a warning.

But it seems this is not the way to go either because the resulting system lacks xorg-server and does not boot into gui.

This was because i skipped default.preseed entirely which is what i now try to recover.